# Layout- Should the output and input traces of this hex inverter be superposed

Tags: pcb, layout, trace

I am using this [hex inverter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74HC14N/277223) in one of my pcbs; the inputs are TTLs, so fast switching signals going from 0 to 5V very fast  ( I don't know yet the rise time of these signals, maybe  10 us ?). Both the input and the inverted output connect to the load.

Question: from a layout point of view is there any reason the input and the output (i.e the inverted input) traces should be superposed or close to each other, or should they on the contrary be far apart not to interfere with each other, should I do left or right picture :

[image]

Comment: 10 μs rise time is not really fast switching, you probably don't need to take that much care.

Comment: FYI, TTL level signals should be switching in some nanoseconds, and the output from 74HC is generally under 5ns with little/no loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to minimize the coupling between the input and output, so offset traces would be a good choice. However, it probably doesn't make much difference over the distance shown and the edge rates. 
More important is power bypass capacitors on the each part and good idea to have a solid ground plane, or at least a grounding scheme with as much copper as possible.

BTW, 10 us edge rate is very slow for logic, so slow that logic may false unless you use a Schmitt-triggered input like the 7414. For the 74HC14, edge rates are in the 10 ns range which is considered slow in today's logic families, but fast enough to practice good high-speed design layout.

Answer (score 3):

By a massive factor (~thousands, say), more important is having a ground plane under the chip at all.

Traces superposed for some ~cm, with risetimes of several ns (wavefront ~0.5m long in electrical length terms), have essentially no effect, especially for digital signals where the noise margin is a good 30% or so of the full edge.

Ground must not be routed by thin traces, but poured around all other traces.  That is, if at all possible, any given trace should be surrounded by ground on at least one side (the opposite layer), and when not, ground should never be more than a modest distance away (laterally).  Close any loops, gaps or openings in ground (on either layer) by "stitching" with ground vias.

This makes traces into transmission lines of consistent geometry (constant cross section along the length, namely as microstrip or CPWG), reducing leakage (emissions and susceptibility) and keeping signal quality good.  (Not that signal quality is much of a priority at the ~ns timescale, but it's still good practice for when it does matter.)

Typically, prioritizing both component placement (for SMTs; THT obviously doesn't matter so much) and routing on one layer, and routing only short jumper sections on the opposite layer, is a straightforward way to ensure good grounding.

In any case, note that any traces cutting across the ground pour, on a given layer, create negative space and a slot or gap in it.  These slots or gaps should be stitched around.  Where two traces or buses cross over, a hole is necessarily made in both ground pours, with a perimeter around the opening; the perimeter can be stitched to minimize its loop length.